# Xcode 8 file indentation: How to set 2 spaces as default configuration?

Tags: xcode, xcode8

I am trying to set the default indentation and tabs in Xcode 8.x to 2 spaces

In the utilities I changes the default values from `4` to `2`

[image: Xcode Text Settings screenshot]

However nothing has changed. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to go to every file and then to Command + A then Ctrl + I which will indent the file with the two spaces. That setting does not touch files already created in the project.

Comment: thank you for your answer, it worked. However, I also had to change to standard view it was not working in assistant editor.

Answer (score 22):

If you want to do this for all projects, you can set this globally in the 
Text Editing / Indentation preferences:

[image: Text Editing / Indentation]